# Dirichlet times odd function

Tags: calculus, functions

Just wanted to verify that in spite of the fact that odd function times even is odd, when I'm multiplying Dirichlet times $F(x) = x$ the function is even.

Comment: No.  If the function you're multiplying by $x$ is even, the result is odd.

Comment: It's odd, just because - as you said - it is a product of an odd and an even function. Dirichlet's function is even , $f(x)=x$ (also known as the identity function) is odd.

Comment: I would like to ask another question - Is the product that i mentioned above is intergable? feels like not.

Comment: It is, and in fact you can do integrate it over the entire real line